# access to resource not allowed on login

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I can access first screen for login though after it returns access not allowed to local resource

it works well in browser 
( I am able to run my project in angular well in a web browser but because it is a desktop application I have to use electron, when I build to run in electron, it starts well, displays login but when I press login instead of returning display it return a white screen and in console, access to resource not allowed

[image]
main.js

```
win.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, './angular_build/index.html'),
    protocol:'file:',
    slashes: true
}));
```

package.json

```
"version": "0.0.0",
"main": "main.js",
"build": {
  "directories": {
     "output": "release/"
  }
},
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "electron": "electron .",
    "electron-build": "ng build --prod && electron ."
},
```

Comment: Can you please provide more explanation to your question.

Comment: I have added so